# Elasticsearch Show duplicate hits

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

How to fix duplicate issue in elasticsearch result ? or can we javascript to remove duplicate recode like this ?

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "yourservice",
    "_type": "categories",
    "_id": "AVGbSNBXiBkfr-xhHUl8",
    "_score": 0.40062606,
    "_timestamp": 1450009219159,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Home Theater "
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "yourservice",
    "_type": "categories",
    "_id": "AVGbR7mdiBkfr-xhHUY2",
    "_score": 0.38263628,
    "_timestamp": 1450009147805,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Home Theater "
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "yourservice",
    "_type": "categories",
    "_id": "AVGbSNBXiBkfr-xhHUo-",
    "_score": 0.33147845,
    "_timestamp": 1450009219159,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Landscape, Yard & Garden"
    }
  }
]
```

}

I have seen some duplicate remove using elasticsearcg aggs but that are not working.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, these entries are not duplicates. Each of it has different _id, _timestamp and _score. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: While i use autocomplete jquery it's show me Home Theater, Home Theater 2 time i want one only.

Comment: Don't now why inserted id 2 times i just simply added records

Comment: so the question is why do you have such records in your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to handle this

1. Create _id based on the fields which define uniqueness of the document. Then use _create API to create document. Here duplicate documents would be rejected to be indexed.
2. Use terms aggregation to see the duplicate documents. Use the terms aggregation on the require field combination to detect duplicate elements and then manually delete them.

There is a good deal of explanation and code example on how to do these in this [blog](https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch).

Comment: Thanks, i created records by using _id and not duplicates in autocomplete.